# SXA 500 error handling

Tags: sxa

I have set up Server Error Page Link field at SXA settings item, but it never 
redirect me to a page, in case of 500 error happen. (400 error works well)

what I should do for make it work ?

I know that SXA should generate static page , errorhandling:generatestaticpage command should be called. but I don't know how to call it from UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that button start appear only on   items based on /sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Multisite/Site template. 
logic inside of code just hide buttons if item not based on site template.

```
public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
        {
            if (context.Items.Length != 0 && context.Items.First<Item>().DoesItemInheritFrom(Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Templates.SiteDefinition.ID))
            {
                return CommandState.Enabled;
            }
            return CommandState.Hidden;
        }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or just an update to the question?